# DOMDocument removing closing tag within script tags

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I have the following `test.php` file, and when I run it, the closing `</h1>` tag gets removed.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML('<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            console.log("<h1>hello</h1>");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>');

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Here is the result when I execute the file:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : h1 in Entity, line: 4 in /home/ryan/NetBeansProjects/blog/test.php on line 14

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            console.log("<h1>hello");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, why is it removing the tag? It's a string so shouldn't it ignore it?

Comment: As a guess I think that the tag is removed because it is in the script element so the slash might need to be escaped. Try putting the <h1>hello</h1> within the body and see what happens.

Comment: It does the same thing within the body. I did read however, that `loadXML()` supports this. I tried it and it doesn't remove the tag, but then I get errors when it isn't valid valid when I load external html files.

Comment: what if you invert your quotes, or escape it like this `console.log(\"<h1>hello</h1>\");`

Comment: Nope, neither of those methods work.

Answer (score 5):

The only solution that comes to mind is to preg match the script tags, then replace them with a temporary holder like `<script id="myuniqueid"></script>` and at the end of dom management replace again with the actual script, like this:

```
//  The dom doc
$doc = new DOMDocument();

//  The html
$html = '<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            console.log("<h1>hello</h1>");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>';

//  Patter for scripts
$pattern = "/<script([^']*?)<\/script>/";
//  Get all scripts
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);

//  Only unique scripts
$matches = array_unique( $matches[0] );

//  Construct the arrays for replacement
foreach ( $matches as $match ) {
  //  The simple script
  $id = uniqid('script_');
  $uniqueScript = "<script id=\"$id\"></script>";
  $simple[] = $uniqueScript;
  //  The complete script
  $complete[] = $match;
}

//  Replace the scripts with the simple scripts
$html = str_replace($complete, $simple, $html);
//  load the html into the dom
$doc->loadHTML( $html);

//  Do the dom management here
//  TODO: Whatever you do with the dom

//  When finished
//  Get the html back
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
//  Replace the scripts back
$html = str_replace($simple, $complete, $html);
//Print the result
echo $html;
```

This solution prints clean without dom errors.

Answer (score 5):

Pass `LIBXML_SCHEMA_CREATE` to loadHTML options. That will fix the issue.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc->loadHTML(
  '<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            console.log("<h1>hello</h1>");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>',
  LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_SCHEMA_CREATE
);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to replace `</TAG>` with `<\/TAG>`:

```
<?php
$html = <<<'EOD'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    console.log("<h1>hello</h1>");
    var foo = '<a href="#"></a>';
    var bar = "<a href=\"#\"></a>";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
EOD;

preg_match_all('/<script\b[^>]*>.*?<\/script>/s', $html, $matches);
$matches = array_unique( $matches[0] );
if( !empty($matches) ) {
    foreach ( $matches as $matches__value ) {
        $before = $matches__value;
        $after = $matches__value;
        preg_match_all('/<\/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*>/', $matches__value, $matches_inner);
        $matches_inner = array_unique( $matches_inner[0] );
        if( !empty($matches_inner) ) {
            foreach($matches_inner as $matches_inner__value) {
                if($matches_inner__value === '</script>') { continue; }
                $after = str_replace($matches_inner__value, str_replace('/','\/',$matches_inner__value), $after);
            }
            $simple[] = $after;
            $complete[] = $before;
        }
    }
    $html = str_replace($complete, $simple, $html);
}

$DOMDocument = new \DOMDocument();
$DOMDocument->loadHTML($html);
$html = $DOMDocument->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```